# How can I confirm if the page that i created using window.open window.document.write is loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to print using js.

below a sample of my code.  it's work but sometimes it shows the print dialog

before the document completely loaded

```
let myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow");

let receiptHtml = app.$refs.receipt.innerHTML; // html to print


waitLoadingAndPrint();

function waitLoadingAndPrint() {
    if (myWindow && !myWindow.closed && myWindow.document ) {

        myWindow.document.write(receiptHtml);

        myWindow.print();

        myWindow.close();


    } else if (myWindow && !myWindow.closed) {

        setTimeout(waitLoadingAndPrint, 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: use the 'load' event

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the way with an iframe

```
     let myWindow = window.frames["printf"];


   let printScript =   '<script>if(typeof printCopies === "undefined"){ let printCopies = 0;}  printCopies = '+ app.printCopies + ';  function printDocument(){if(printCopies > 0){   for(let i= printCopies ; i>= 0; i--){  window.print(); } } else{ window.print();}} </script>';

    myWindow.document.write( printScript + '<body onload="printDocument()">'+receiptHtml '</body>'  );
```